# convert filter configartion in web.xml to spring.xml

Tags: java, spring, servlets, servlet-filters

I have created a filter and configured in my web.xml as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
        <display-name>Your Web App</display-name>
        <filter>
                <description>Test Filter</description>
                <display-name>Hello world filter</display-name>
                <filter-name>HelloWorldFilter</filter-name>
                <filter-class>com.abc.HelloWorld</filter-class> 
        <init-param>
                <param-name>greet</param-name>
                <param-value>Good Morning</param-value>
        </init-param>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>HelloWorldFilter</filter-name>
                <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
                <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        </filter-mapping>
        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>NyServlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>com.abc.myservlet</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>NyServlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now I am working on Springs. I want to include this in Spring.xml. I am not having any servlet but I  have  a normal class as bean.

Please suggest how to add this info in spring.xml

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have this in your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <display-name>HelloWorldFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>MyServlet</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyServlet</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and following in applicationContext.xml (or Spring.xml in your case)

```
<bean id="helloWorldFilter" class="com.abc.HelloWorldFilter"> </bean>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. <filter-name>MyServlet</filter-name> is this valid. How to set the servlet to this filter and Request dispatcher here.

Comment: all the requests are router through `DelegatinFilterProxy` of Spring to your Spring Bean i.e `com.abc.HelloWorldFilter`

Comment: Thank you. I hope I can set <init-param> inside the bean.